# Scipy optimize def functions vs lambda

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Is it normal to have different results between:
Using a lambda expression
And using def function
To express constraints with scipy optimizer
I ll add code later

Comment: Lambda and first class functions not equivalent, for instance the latter have closure the former do not.

Comment: Any documentation?  Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture has a lot of insights, don't know about a proper documentation page

Comment: Share your code and we can look at your specific case.

Comment: If the functon/lambda depends only on the passed arguments, they should be the same.  But if they use a some additional variable that you expect to define either a definition time or runtime, you could run into problems.  e.g.  `lambda x: x+i`, what `i` is being used?

Answer (score 0):

They should be identical unless you're (ab)using somewhat esoteric language features, e.g. pulling variables from outer scopes.

So most likely, there's an issue in your code.